# suspicious linksys WRT54GH router behaviour - AND a bad line?

Tags: wireless-networking, router, internet-speed, wrt54g

I've got what I think is a bad broadband line, but I also think there's an additional problem with the router (a Linksys WRT54GH). Could someone let me know if I'm just unlucky, or if there's something I should look at? For various reasons (one being that I'm in a company house) it will be difficult getting an engineer out.

B/b connection is slow/unstable - typically receives data at less than 10KB/s. It can go up as high as 100KB/s, but tends to fall right back down to near 0 after a second or two. Late at night the connection can maintain around 40-50KB/s for several minutes at a time. I didn't set up the line but believe it is high speed.

This is using wifi, or with ethernet to the router. I also plugged the b/b line straight into my laptop - I wasn't sure what would happen but it identified a network and I could access the internet, but with the same speed issues (I didn't try it for long but if anything the speed was worse). That's why I think the line is bad. Under control panel -> network connections -> Network 3 (the active network) it listed the speed of the connection as 100Mbps.

Before that I was trying to look at the router settings. Here is why I think the router also has a problem:

- the wifi had no password set; I thought people might be stealing    bandwidth. Tried to log on to router settings (192.168.1.1) using the default username    & password and couldn't get in.
- tried to log in using IE instead of    FF - had to log in FIVE times before it accepted it. Every time I    click a button or access a page, I need to enter login credentials,    again five times. The 'remember my details' check box does not work.
- found the list of devices connected via wifi, there were indeed    several that should not have been, including a surly next door    neighbour who has her own wifi (with a password so we can't use it)    so wasn't too pleased about that
- found the wifi password security    set to 'disabled', put it to WPA2, clicked save, was asked to enter login details - this time I entered them three times and it gave me a    401 not authorised error. Same thing when I try to change any    setting, not just the password
- is there such a thing as having two    sets of router passwords, one for higher level access?
- factory reset the router, no change
- factory reset the router again, went as quickly as i    could to 192.168.1.1 and this time it accepted my login first time. Added a wifi password and hit save. Had to enter details five times    again but it saved
- tried to change another setting and it went back to the 401 screen - evidently there is only time to change one thing    before something comes alive and blocks you

  1. Router - is this some sort of malware/virus? Or could it be a security feature set by my employer that I have accidently circumvented? It's a weird security feature that leaves wifi with no password though.
  2. My broadband - noise on the line perhaps? Is there any way I can test this without having to ask my facilities manager to get an engineer in? She says she’s had people look at it before (but can't seem to recall what they said).

Thanks

**EDIT**

Router does not seem to have a stats page.

Pathping below

NB. I entered 'bbc.co.uk' but this is evidently automatically updated to 'net.uk'
NB2. The router has its own traceroute function, but this timed out once it got to step 5, had several more time outs, and finally reported: "13 610 ms 610 ms 610 ms www.bbc.co.uk [212.58.244.66]"

---

Tracing route to www.bbc.net.uk [212.58.244.66]
over a maximum of 30 hops:
  0  laptop [192.168.1.xxx]
  1  192.168.1.1
  2  10.xxx.xxx.1
  3  10.xxx.xxx.78
  4     *     10.xxx.xxx.1
  5  10.xxx.xxx.2
  6     *        *        *
Computing statistics for 125 seconds...
            Source to Here   This Node/Link
Hop  RTT    Lost/Sent = Pct  Lost/Sent = Pct  Address
  0..............................................................laptop [192.168.1.xxx]
............................................0/ 100 =  0%   |
  1.....6ms....0/ 100... = 0%....0/ 100 = 0% 192.168.1.1
...........................................0/ 100 =  0%   |
  2....10ms...0/ 100... = 0%....0/ 100 = 0% 10.xxx.xxx.1
...........................................0/ 100 =  0%   |
  3..562ms...0/ 100... = 0%....0/ 100 = 0%  10.xxx.xxx.78
...........................................0/ 100 =  0%   |
  4..567ms...2/ 100... = 2%....2/ 100 = 2%  10.xxx.xxx.1
...........................................0/ 100 =  0%   |
  5..567ms...0/ 100... = 0%....0/ 100 = 0%  10.xxx.xxx.2

Trace complete.

Comment: A pathping to a known good destination (www.bbc.co.uk) might be interesting. [Edit] your question to include the results. If it is an ADSL connection your line stats might also be usefull (if your router provides them).

Comment: happy to do so - assume i should redact my own IP address, and/or others?

Comment: Redacting is good -- at least your public ip address if it appears -- pathping doesn't show mine :)

Comment: If you are worried that your router might have been compromised by your neighbor, and if you are aware of reconfiguring the router, try to reset the router and configure it afresh. It's always a good idea to setup a password for your router. Top check if you have problem with the broadband line, you should check the SNR value listed (on the WAN page, probably) when connected to the internet.

Comment: Thanks Charles. I have already tried a factory reset of the router. This frees up access to router options and allows me to change settings for just a few seconds - before it then locks everything. I chose to add a wifi password in that limited time. This makes me wonder if there is some sort of malware, or if modified firmware has been flashed onto the router.

Answer (score 0):

I could not see any indication (from your post) that the problem is the router - it would seem to me more likely to be an issue with the broadband connection and/or data line entering your house.

You have not advised the type of connection you had, but I would focus on that.  If its ADSL or similar, try (temporarily) unplugging all phones and filters, plugging only the ADSL router directly into the wall and see if that improves things.   If there is a slight improvement its probably an issue related to the exchange/copper/distance.   If there is a substantial improvement you most likely have a faulty filter - this is quite common.   If you don't get any change then that does not tell you anything (ie it could still be a problem with the ADSL)

I also observe a lot of the IP addresses in your traceroute start 10.x.x.x - This, along with the latencies - tends to imply an incompetent company masquerading as an ISP - ie it may not be a problem with your connection it might be your ISP.  (It could be legitimate, but it would be highly unusual for a provider to use that much RFC1918 IP space in their network).   Who is your ISP ?    Also, do you need this for work, and if so is there a VPN?  That could explain the problems - and the business may be artificially limiting the connection speed.

Comment: Thanks David. I agree, I think there is a problem with the line. But also with router. Could be coincidence; would still value insights. Presume the line is ADSL but don't know - it's clearly not e.g. cable. No other phones/filters in the property, prob some in adjoining house. The router is connected straight to the wall. Not using VPN (on personal laptop). Are there any tests or checks I can run to convince my facilities manager to look into this ('it's slow' doesn't seem to work). Colleagues nearby are not having quite the same difficulties (we're not in UK so no-one has amazing service)

Comment: To clarify - whether it is directly impacting the speed issues or not, something is not right with the router and that makes me uncomfortable.

Comment: Why do you think the problem is with the router ?  The way I do it (I used to run an ISP so know more then most) is to run a continuous ping and monitor the latency and packet loss, and also graph the utilization.  How I did that is really beyond the scope of a SU question - but I have proven to more then 1 ISP they have a problem when they initially denied it.  That said, your traceroutes alone show an issue - Mabye run MTR/WinMTR for a few hours and provide that - 500+ ms latency after hop 3 shows a definate issue most providers should accept.

Comment: Thanks David. I'll look into MTR (I'll need to do some research). The router is displaying very odd behaviour, even after a factory reset it has no wifi password by default, and it is strange that it will only allow me to add a password/change settings for just a few seconds after a factory reset, then will block me. Also having to enter passwords five times to gain access to router options is strange.

Answer (score 0):

Your probably is most definitely your cable/dsl connection. If I understood correctly, you plugged your modem directly into your PC once, so if it was slow at the point, your router is not at fault. It would suggest calling your ISP and working your slow connection out with them. You could also try restarting your modem and see if that does anything.

Comment: Thanks MM. I connected my wall socket directly to my laptop using an ethernet cable and got internet connection, but it was still slow (presume my laptop has in-built modem to deal with this). Agree, seems to point to the line. Can I check noise on the line or do other tests at this point? My facilities manager is not keen on calling the ISP (as my house is the only one complaining, of several). Btw, any thoughts on what IS wrong with the router? Something is not right, even if it is not related to the main problem.

Comment: What you have here is a strange problem. Usually, resetting a router and then using default credentials (typically admin/password, or listed on bottom of router.) Obviously, you have already done that. I would suggest looking on the bottom of your router and seeing if there's some info there: there's a ton of info on ours that helps for debugging purposes. Also, for setup, try using Ethernet instead of WiFi, that can eliminate some problems.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with login credentials is very odd, never seen it. However theoretically it may be caused by two Wifi access points using the same SSID, and both without Wifi password. Your computer may just switching between two APs, yours another unknown router.

So please connect your computer with Ethernet cable to router, turn Wifi OFF in computer and check everything again.

Answer (score 0):

I recently had a nearly identical login credentials problem with a Netgear wifi router. Some googling suggested the cause is a UPNP vulnerability.  I solved the problem by disabling UPNP, blocking the UPNP port (5000/tcp), and power cycling the router.  Good luck and hope this helps.